# Baritone or Tenor?

Tags: vocal-range

I was classified recently by two different peeople as Lyric Baritone and Spinto Tenor, and i just want other opinions. First of all i am an untrained male voice, 30 years. I have had some trouble to find my voice type. My total range include airy lower register and mixed voice is F2-A4, but my singable comfortable range is A2-G4. I feel like i can mix more than A4, but i don't know how to, i have a crack so that's why am not able, but i can go in head voice without falsetto about C5-Db5 and in falsetto up to Bb5-B5. I have a natural quality high G. I will shaRe here a link with my audio, i don't sound very well, but i hope you can listen and find my voice type. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, just so you know, this sort of question is pretty hard to answer properly without just saying 'talk to a teacher'. Here's some background information: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/vocal-type-questions. The answers there do mention a canonical 'what's my voice type' question, but I can't seem to locate it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You love to sing!  You can extend your range well beyond what is obvious.  Relax and blow.

At the high end, think "ee" but voice "oo."  At the low end, think "oo" and voice "aa."